# full calendar google event not showing

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I apologise if this has already been answered, but I am having difficulty getting my calendar to display events that i have entered in google calendar.

can someone look at my code and tell me what I am missing?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-2.2.5/fullcalendar.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar-master/dist/gcal.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                googleCalendarApiKey: '<AIzaSyD6vDNaab25QZdjAqggmjT1_BvCa_9WeEY>',
                events: { 
                googleCalendarId: 'lichfieldrooms@gmail.com',
                      className: 'gcal-event',
                        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/lichfieldrooms%40gmail.com/public/basic'
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I think your `googleCalendarId` value is NOT correct. From the documentation this Id should `look something like that 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com'`

Comment: also as @iubema said, the ApiKey is without '<', '>'.

Comment: It's really weird. All I can see is (Calendar ID: lichfieldrooms@gmail.com) I can't seen anywhere with the mentioned example anywhere on my settings at all :(

Comment: The CalendarID format in your question is the same as IDs of non-public calendars, maybe you failed to make your calendar public. See the steps for making it public here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

Comment: I have followed all the instructions on the Full Calendar website to make my calendar public. I have reported the issue with Google also but I have no idea how long they will take to reply :(

Comment: Ok I've created a new calendar and it is now displaying a correct calendar ID. It is still not working(?) Do I have to style the bookings in CSS or HTML somewhere in order for them to display?

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code and the documentation of full calendar and google calendar all seems to be ok but i think your ApiKey is not ok, try to write it without '<' '>'.

edit:
Also, in your code the second event should be follow this formats http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/#options

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but every time I have been running google calendar with full calendar I haven't included the google "feeds" in the "events" section. Rather I called it like so:

```
var gCalId = //your google calendar ID   
var gApi = //your google API

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventSources: [
            {
                url: gCalId,    
            }
        ],
   });  


});
```

You can also call it like(assuming that you are including the API elsewhere):

```
events: {   
   googleCalendarId: gCalId,
        },
```

I am sort of new at it, but those have been working for me.
Also the documentation from Full Calendar explains this by omission, but if you are using a "Google Apps" Calendar rather than a normal "Google Calendar" your public sharing options will be different. If you are using "Google Apps" your Administrator will need to turn on:

"Share all information, and allow managing of calendars" 
OR
"Share all information, but outsiders cannot change calendars"
These are in the Admin Console->under Google Apps->Google Calendar.
After you adjust this setting THEN you can go back to your Sharing settings on your Google Apps Calendar and check off "Make this Calendar public" AND THEN you can now select "see all event details".

Otherwise, your Full Calendar will only display the Event Blocks, but it will not show Titles, or any other information.

Using a separate Google Calendar outside of my Google Apps account worked of course because Full Calendar explains how to do this with just a normal Google Calendar.

Let me know if that information helped? I am a newbie programmer that has been wrestling with Javascript, FullCalendar, and the Google APIs for the past 2 weeks.